# d3.js (svg) path directionality vs. marker-end, hive plots

Tags: svg, d3.js, path, trigonometry, markers

**Scenario:**

I am currently working with d3.js Hive Plots, and for an experimental scenario, I need control of the visual directionality of the links.

**Problem Source:**

I am using d3.hive.v0.js "add-on", and due to the fact that Hive Plots charts do not inherently carry any visual directionality information on the links, the add-on does not adhere to source and target nodes with regards to directionality of the drawn path, and always draws the paths clockwise, and hence always pointing in the direction of the node to the left when snapping on a marker-end.

**Problem Effect**

Pointers are unreliable because the path "end" that the marker adheres to, is not nescessarily at the target, but may be at the source, depending on the source and targets relative position to each other.

**What it boils down to**

I know that I could draw my own links with my own Arcs and gain more control, instead of using the d3 Hive Plot library links, and I have tried it, but it's not easy to get nice, and the Hive Plot algorithm is pretty and I would like to use it.

Let's say I intercept d, when it comes back from the Hive Plot link path algo.

I find d = "M 8.327598234202001e-15,-136 C 101.06769626492562,-91.00176246480473 135.0052608777338,14.189624701397365 79.7912059004442,109.82317321396422";

That gives me a nice path, starting in the top, and drawing down (CW) as demostrated in

http://jsfiddle.net/hwehqhtm/1/

```
svg.selectAll(".test")
    .data(d3.range(1))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", "green")
    .attr("stroke-width", 3)
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)")
    .attr("d", d)
```

My question is, now that I have d, is it possible to "reverse the draw direction" of the line by doing something on d ? , - making "path end" be the top end of the line, and make the marker-end go here, effectivly making the link point the other direction.

The line should be visually identical, only logically "beginning" in the other end.

The parent fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hwehqhtm uses two different markers for start and end, but then I would have to include new logic in some marker-end and marker-start callbacks to switch them on off, and I would really prefer to just mathemagically make it draw "the other way" by "reversing d" if possible. I'm not good enough at trig to know if this even makes sense. Any comments and solutions on path directionality and markers are very welcome !

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it can be done by switching around the parameters. The d above, created by the hive plot algorithm turns out to be a moveto and a curveto (bezier) in the format M x y C x1 y1 x2 y2 x y.

[image]

To reverse the curve, switching endpoint x,y in C with startpoint x,y in M and then switching the bezier control points x1,y1 with x2,y2 seems to do it.